# Telling the CsvProvider which line contains the column headers

Tags: f#-data

Is there a way to tell the FSharp.Data CsvProvider that the column headers are on the second rather than the first line?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, but it sounds like something that could be added. Feel free to [submit a feature request](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues?state=open), or even better a pull request :-).

It would be useful to know more details (it is not exactly standard format of CSV files). Is there something on the first line, or is it blank (we could just skip all blank lines at the beginning....) or is there some sort of "comment"?

Comment: In the financial domain csv files are often structured. For example the file may contain a line with meta information that comes before the list of column headings the data limes are then often followed by a footer line which will contain a record count and debit/credit totals. Also common is a batching structure with batch headers and footers in addition to the file headers and footers.

Comment: @user2329716 Well, that's ugly :-) not particularly according to the RFC! But I guess we'll have to do something to support this. If you can find some publicly available samples of such CSVs (or anything that you could share) and post it at the GitHub page, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SkipRows parameter for that:
http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-csvprovider.html